# MUI V5 Why us Box with Grid component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm using MUI to learn some react for the first time. I'm wondering why use the `Box` component along with the `Grid` component. From the [docs](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-grid2/) it shows this as an example

```
export default function BasicGrid() {
  return (
    <Box sx={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
      <Grid container spacing={2}>
        <Grid xs={8}>
          <Item>xs=8</Item>
        </Grid>
        <Grid xs={4}>
          <Item>xs=4</Item>
        </Grid>
        <Grid xs={4}>
          <Item>xs=4</Item>
        </Grid>
        <Grid xs={8}>
          <Item>xs=8</Item>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

I removed the `Box` component applying any props to the outermost `Grid` and everything seems the same, I think. Is there an advantage to wrapping a `Grid` component with a `Box`? Any help in would be great!

Removing outer most container seems to do nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Box` = `div`

Check it out here: https://github.com/mui/material-ui/blob/master/packages/mui-material/src/Box/Box.js

Which just calls this: https://github.com/mui/material-ui/blob/master/packages/mui-system/src/createBox.js

It's a div that accepts camelCase css props and adhere's to MUI's styling system rules, that's it - it's a div

Almost everywhere you see `Box` used, replace it with `div` with the inline CSS props and you'll have the same thing

In your code example, it would only make sense if it were the child of a `flex` container. Otherwise, it literally does absolutely nothing (that a normal `div` doesn't), because `flex-grow` is only relevant inside `flex` containers.

Comment: ah okay. Is this a correct statement - `Box` is used as a wrapper to provide access to extra css props? Then in this case it seems `Box` isn't needed because the `Grid` component also has access to those props like this 


```<Grid container
          display="flex"
          spacing={1} 
          columns={timeUnit} 
          justifyContent="space-evenly"
          marginTop={2} ></Grid
```

Comment: In your code example, `Box` appears useless. I really can’t elaborate, nor think anything else is necessary aside from `Box` = `div`

Comment: I appreciate the answer!